# If Angular modules are independent, why do I not have to RouterModule in the App Module?

Tags: angular, routes, module

Suppose that we have 4 modules:

- `AppRouting.module`
- `Recipe.module`
- `RecipeRouting.module`
- `App.module`

We are also dealing with the angular made module: `RouterModule`

`AppRouting.module` 's ngModule looks like this:

```js
 imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],

  exports: [RouterModule]
```

`RecipeRouting.module` 's module looks like this:

```js
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
```

`Recipe.module` 's ngModule looks like this

```js
exports: [
    // bunch of components and directives
  ],
imports: [
    RecipeRoutingModule
  ]
```

Finally the `App.module` looks like this

```js
// we import a bunch of necessary modules
 imports: [
 AppRouteModule,
 RecipesModule
  ],
// why is it that we don't have to import the `RecipeRouting.module`?
```

As the question stated in the last snippet, why do we not import `RecipeRouting.module` in the App Module? I have a feeling that it has to do with the `RouterModule` because that's the only thing we are exporting in that module and we are already importing the `RouterModule` and we already made changes to the class using `forChild`?

Any explanation would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its because when you import the router module of another module, it overrides the default routing configured in `app.routing.module.ts`**

`Routes of RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)` -> get's overridden by `RecipeRouting.module Routes`

The `RecipeRouting.module` is mean't to be an import of `RecipeModule` and we need to load the `RecipeModule` as a lazy/eager loaded module!